# How to connect to remote server with different enviromental.?

Tags: node.js, ssh

I am trying to connect the remote computing server and trying to run the command on it.

Connection is successful, but the command is not running. It looks like, it is changing to some other environment. So I need to run the command over there.

```
conn.on('ready', () => {
    conn.exec(command, (err, stream) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        let x = '';
        stream.on('close', (code, signal) => {
            console.log("x is ",x)
            conn.end();
        }).on('data', (data) => {
            x += data.toString();
        }).stderr.on('data', (data) => {
            node.send(msg);

        });
    });
}).connect(sshConfig);
```

and with the above code it is printing only the following line, `Your last successful login was at 2023-6-28 11:43:55` but not running the command